# Primeface´s remoteCommand - there is a way to execute once?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

Primefaces 3.5 JSF 2.1

I´m using p:remoteCommand to execute async commands and update my view after page loading but looks that in the ends of each iteration it execute again and so on...

Is this behaviour correct?

How to execute only once the p:remoteCommand?

**update**

I have checked that my remoteCommand was out of the update panel, so thank you for the answers but it was already OK. How I solve my problem:

I dont know why but using the onloadScript from  Omnifaces (http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript) to call the remoteCommand function it is called many times, but using $(document).ready ... just once. So, I change it and got it working right now.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet you tried?

Comment: You are like updating a parent component to your <p:remoteCommand>. Put it outside the component you wish to update

Comment: @AkselWillgert, I´m not in my workstation right now but your answer looks fine! Try use Answer feature and not a comment, so I can check it as correct when I validate it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you end up in an infinite loop like behaviour, you are likely updating a parent component to your `<p:remoteCommand>`.

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <p:remoteCommand update="myform" actionListener="#{remoteCommandView.execute}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

Put it outside/next to the component you wish to update and things should be fine.

```
<h:form id="newform">
<p:remoteCommand update="myform" actionListener="#{remoteCommandView.execute}" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="myform">
...
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hehe, someone evil was down voting it and as I remember the answer should solve the problem :)

Comment: Well, someone voted it up now since it is "really correct" now ..Honestly, good thing to maintain old questions !

Answer (score 4):

Use `p:remoteCommand` in separate form.
Use `process="@this"` and `partialSubmit="true"`, just to be on safer side.